# Can you help me understand this sentence? I can't distinguish the words and grammar patterns

Tags: grammar, words, particle-だけ

Sentence: 喋れるだけましってものです.

Context: the main character has gone through a lot and lost his memories but he is all right physically. Another person is saying that sentence to the main character. I guess the sentence means that it is good that he can at least speak after all that happened but what is ましってもの and how does it work with だけ here?

Comment: Basic division to help you - 喋れる・だけ・まし・って・もの・です

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two points of grammar here, first of all だけましだ which means "it's better than ~ bla bla" or "one should be grateful" (you can learn more about it, just [here](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%A0-dake-mashi-da-meaning/) )

So until here, it's something like "Being able to speak is better than nothing" or "we should be grateful that you're able to speak" and the second point of grammar is ものだ which can be used to state an obvious fact (which doesn't change anything in the English translation). You can learn more about [here](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A0-%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-mono-da-mono-janai-meaning/)